# Passing an array and an object in one ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, object

I've asked before if i can pass an object to an ajax request to be sent to my rest service. Now my question is if i can pass an object can i pass array and object in one single ajax request? Any replies will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can either send an object containing an array or an array containing an object, but not both simultaneously:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    data: { obj: {}, arr: [] }
});

$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    data: [{}, {}, {}]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course.

```
var o = {};
var a = [];

{obj: o, arr: a}
```

You will of course have to have code on the server side to interpret it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

sure, just send one object containing them.  i.e.

```
{
   arrayToSend: ['a','b','c'],
   objectToSend: {name:'thescientist'}
}
```